# Expression.Error: Can´t be applied the * operator to List and number Types

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

i'm trying to insert new a formula in power query to get the total of sales.

I'm getting this error:

> Expression.Error: Can´t be applied the * operator to List and number Types.

I'm folowing a webinar session and they are using this formula:

> {[#"Unit Price (USD)"]*[Quantity]}*(1-[Discount]))

Any suggestions?

I'm expectating to get the Sales totals from those products.

- Quantity = Number
- Discount = Float
- Unit Price USD = Number

The expected result it's a float sales value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you pasted your code correctly, but likely the { is making the code think you are using a list, which is usually written as **{something}**

It should probably be something like this, which does not include the {

```
([#"Unit Price (USD)"]*[Quantity]*(1-[Discount]))
```